# add json elements to variable

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I have some troubles. I want to configure google maps and add point from json file. I want to add 'lat' and 'lng' to my 'features' variable(loop each json file element of 'results'), but it's not working.

json file

```
{"act":"success","totalResults":122,"results":[{"id":"1","lat":"50.162292","lng":"-5.089257"},{"id":"2","lat":"50.164001","lng":"-5.069998"},{"id":"3","lat":"50.106697","lng":"-5.549815"},{"id":"4","lat":"50.129349","lng":"-5.515587"},{"id":"5","lat":"50.129333","lng":"-5.515833"},{"id":"6","lat":"50.128429","lng":"-5.519022"},{"id":"7","lat":"50.186115","lng":"-5.421418"},{"id":"8","lat":"50.225258","lng":"-5.274623"},{"id":"9","lat":"50.261471","lng":"-5.067650"}]}
```

script code

```
<script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapGoogle'), {
          zoom: 7,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.509865, -0.118092),
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
          gestureHandling: 'greedy',
          disableDefaultUI: true
        });

        var myjson;
        $.getJSON("http://app.regain-app.com/rest/V1/points/get?lat=50.164001&lng=-5.069998&distance=26", function(json){
            myjson = json;

            console.log(myjson);
        });

        var icons = {
          info: {
            icon: 'http://www.picpng.com/uploads/small/Google_Map_Marker_Red_Peg_77453.Png'
          }
        };

        var features = [
          {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.162292, -5.089257),
            type: 'info'
          }, {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.164001, -5.069998),
            type: 'info'
          }, {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.106697, -5.549815),
            type: 'info'
          }
        ];

        myjson.results.forEach(function(object){

        });

        // Create markers.
        features.forEach(function(feature) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: feature.position,
            icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
            map: map
          });
        });
      }
    </script>
```

I will be grateful for any help. :)

Comment: You haven't written anything where you loop through the results. Can you show your attempts?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of work to be done here.

First, your loop.
Your loop is in the wrong place.

```
var myjson;
        $.getJSON("http://app.regain-app.com/rest/V1/points/get?lat=50.164001&lng=-5.069998&distance=26", function(json){
            myjson = json;

            console.log(myjson);
        });
```

This is where your program sets the variable myjson. However, it only happens in the callback, so you can't loop them later in your code, so put this code:

```
myjson.results.forEach(function(object){

});
```

inside the callback, and declare your features variable before the callback.

Now in your forEach loop:

```
features.push({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseInt(object.lat), parseInt(object.lng)),
        type: 'info'
      })
```

The push adds a new object to the array, which is defined in the brackets.